# How to reset/clear Android PaginData object and it's adapter?

Tags: android, android-paging-3

I'm using a PagingData inside a ViwModel with a Flow object.
It's working correctly, but my problems is that, a certain point I need to reset/clear it to request new data.

I've tried different methods the objects has, but I haven't been able to do it. So, how can I achieve it?

Int he ViewModel

```
lateinit var items: Flow<PagingData<MyItem>>
    private set

private fun initItemsFlow() {
     items = repository.getItemsData().map { pagingData ->
        pagingData.map { it }
    }.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

This is the repository function:

```
fun getItemsData(): Flow<PagingData<MyItem>> = Pager(
    PagingConfig(pageSize = 10, enablePlaceholders = false, prefetchDistance = 5)
) {
    ItemsPagingSource()
}.flow
```

And finally, this is how I listen to it in the view

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
    viewModel
        .items
        .collect {
            iAdapter.submitData(it)
        }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the best solution, but I ended up creating a new `PagingData` flow when I need to "clear/reset" the list. I have opted for this solution since I didn't find any method to reset the request to the data source.

So, in the fragment:

```
fun onResetList() {
    viewModel.onResetList()
    lifecycleScope.launch { 
        viewModel
            .items
            .collect {
                itemsAdapter.submitData(it)
            }
    }
}
```

And, in the ViewModel I just recreate the flow object:

```
fun onResetList() {
items = repository.getItemsData().map { pagingData ->
        pagingData.map { it }
    }.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With flow I guess you could also do it like this:

```
val getItemsInitializer: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    val items = initItemsInitializer.asFlow()
        .flatMapLatest { Boolean ->

      // your code to get paging data

        }.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

So whenever you post value in getItemsInitializer, it will get new paging data.
Or, with livedata only you could try this :

```
    val items = Transformations.switchMap(getItemsInitializer){
             { 
// get your paging data here 
    }.liveData.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
                 }
```

Practically working same, getting new data when you post value in getItemsInitializer